Creating a 3D polyhedron using matplotlib
Just creating a 3D polyhedron for a little project.
At this time, I have developed the following code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import numpy as np


class Polyhedron:
    """Represent a geometric polyhedron."""

    def __init__(self, volume=0, edges=0, vertices=0, faces=0):
        self.volume = max(volume, 0)
        self.edges = max(edges, 0)
        self.vertices = max(vertices, 0)
        self.faces = max(faces, 0)
        self.valid = self._is_valid()

    def _is_valid(self):
        """Check if the polyhedron has a valid Euler characteristic."""
        return self.vertices - self.edges + self.faces == 2

    def _is_regular(self):
        """Check if the polyhedron is regular."""
        if self.faces == 0:
            return False
        edges_per_face = self.edges / self.faces
        vertices_per_face = self.vertices / self.faces
        return edges_per_face.is_integer() and vertices_per_face.is_integer()

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Polyhedron):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.volume < other.volume

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Polyhedron):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.volume > other.volume

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Polyhedron):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.volume == other.volume

    def scale(self, volume_factor=1, edges_factor=1, vertices_factor=1, faces_factor=1):
        """Scale the polyhedron by a given factor."""
        self.volume *= volume_factor
        self.edges *= edges_factor
        self.vertices *= vertices_factor
        self.faces *= faces_factor
        self.valid = self._is_valid()

    def generate_vertices(self):
        if not self.valid:
            raise ValueError("The polyhedron is not valid.")
        
        vertices = []
        for i in range(self.vertices):
            phi = np.arccos(1 - 2*i/self.vertices)
            theta = np.pi * (1 + np.sqrt(5)) * i
            x = np.cos(theta) * np.sin(phi)
            y = np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi)
            z = np.cos(phi)
            vertices.append([x * self.volume, y * self.volume, z * self.volume])
        return vertices
    
    def generate_edges(self):
        edges = []
        for i in range(self.vertices):
            for j in range(i+1, self.vertices):
                edges.append([i, j])
        return edges
    
    def generate_faces(self):
        if not self.valid:
            raise ValueError("The polyhedron is not valid.")
        
        faces = []
        vertices = []
        edges = self.generate_edges()

        # Create a dictionary to store the adjacent vertices for each vertex
        adjacent_vertices = {i: [] for i in range(self.vertices)}
        for edge in edges:
            v1, v2 = edge
            adjacent_vertices[v1].append(v2)
            adjacent_vertices[v2].append(v1)

        # Create faces by traversing through vertices and their adjacent vertices
        visited_edges = set()
        for v1 in range(self.vertices):
            for v2 in adjacent_vertices[v1]:
                for v3 in adjacent_vertices[v2]:
                    if v3 != v1 and (v1, v2) not in visited_edges and (v2, v3) not in visited_edges and (v3, v1) not in visited_edges:
                        faces.append([v1, v2, v3])
                        visited_edges.add((v1, v2))
                        visited_edges.add((v2, v3))
                        visited_edges.add((v3, v1))
        return faces

    def plot(self, ax):
        """Plot the polyhedron based on the volume, and the number of vertices and edges provided."""
        if not self.valid:
            raise ValueError("The polyhedron is not valid.")
        
        # Plot vertices
        vertices = self.generate_vertices()
        edges = self.generate_edges()
        faces = self.generate_faces()

        ax.scatter([vertex[0] for vertex in vertices],
                   [vertex[1] for vertex in vertices],
                   [vertex[2] for vertex in vertices],
                   c='red', marker='o', s=20)
        
        # Plot edges
        for edge in edges:
            v1, v2 = edge
            ax.plot([vertices[v1][0], vertices[v2][0]],
                    [vertices[v1][1], vertices[v2][1]],
                    [vertices[v1][2], vertices[v2][2]], c='red')
            
        # Plot faces
        faces = self.generate_faces()
        for face in faces:
            face = np.array([vertices[i] for i in face])
            ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection([face], facecolors='black', linewidths=1, edgecolors='red', alpha=0.5))

    def __repr__(self):
        return (
            f"{type(self).__name__}"
            f"(volume={self.volume}, "
            f"edges={self.edges}, "
            f"vertices={self.vertices}, "
            f"faces={self.faces})"
        )

# Example usage
poly = Polyhedron(volume=10, edges=30, vertices=12, faces=20)
if poly.valid:
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6), facecolor='black')
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    poly.plot(ax)
    
    # Hide the axes
    ax.axis('off')

    plt.show()
else:
    print("Invalid polyhedron properties. Please provide valid parameters.")

It is supposed to plot a regular dodecahedron, but 1) it doesn't seem regular and 2) the faces aren't correctly plotted.
I wanted to plot a small stellated dodecahedron as well, but I don't know if my algorithm allows for non-convex shaping, considering it has pretty much a similar combination of edges, vertices, and faces (30, 12, 12)
Can anyone help me?
